# Error in laravel testing : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users

Tags: mysql, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

when I use PHPUnit in laravel and add a factory to my own test class after running PHPUnit appear this error in the console:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users
```

my test class method:

```
public function testExistSomeTextsInIndexPage()
{
    $users= factory(User::class)->create();
    $this->get('/')->assertSee($users->name);
     
}
```

this factory code work correctly in other parts of my project just show the error in the test class

Comment: did you migrate in the setup of the test ?

Comment: where is the setup of the test exactly? I just migrate the main database project

Comment: At the root folder, you have the config file for phpunit, set it to use the same database as the project. usualy, for tests you use a temporary database so you can test everything (creation, modification and deletion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked for me when i insert **use RefreshDatabase**;

Like this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

}
```

Note: Just be careful in my case I use Laravel :memory database, this function deletes all the data that was created

Answer (score 5):

You should include the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations` as a trait. There is [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) about this.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
}
```

**Note**: Set the correct DB credentials. If you use your credentials for you existing DB, it will override the DB. I would advise you to use a `in-memory` DB with SQLite, see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674160/how-to-create-an-in-memory-database-for-phpunit-testing)